# Facing issue while Exporting gridview data to Excel in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

Exporting grid View data in excel is done successfully and downloaded also.

But while opening that excel file following issue come:

[image]

When I press yes it open file with data but when i press no it open blank file.

[image]

Comment: Please try to add the code instead of an image of the code because it is easier for us to run the code and check for errors

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Answer (score 0):

please change your code as below

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"FileName.xlsx\"");
```